# Field 'ProfilePhotoId' on object 'User' is not supported

Tags: apex, user-record

I have been getting this exception when updating lead(Process Builder). While I do not see any issue with process builders update operation I get below exception.

This error occurred:

> FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION: Error:Field 'ProfilePhotoId' on
>   object 'User' is not supported. One or more features must be enabled
>   to access this field.

I am not able to find **ProfilePhotoId** field on User nor there is any documentation around it. What feature is Salesforce expecting me to enable ?

Confirming  there is no such reference in the entire org.

Comment: That field could be part of chatter, is that enabled on your org?

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this error today with a flow.  The error message stating that we were using 'ProfilePhotoId' on User occurred recently with no code or flow changes on our end.  I'm making the assumption that something completely unrelated (a release or patch by SFDC, an upgrade by one of the installed packages, or perhaps a setting turned-on somewhere)?  Regardless of what caused the issue to start out of the blue, I was able to correct the issue by excluding that field from my process that uses `getDescribe().fields.getMap()` to get "all fields" from the User record.  Apparently that field is returned now in the Map, but is not accessible/usable by the process.  I added a specific exclusion to remove that fieldname from the returned map.  The process now works.

Summary: If you are using `getDescribe().fields.getMap()` - you will need to exclude `ProfilePhotoId` from being used for anything.